# Is there any free email client that supports composing right-to-left emails?

Tags: 18.04, language-support, email-client

I have been using Evolution. But it does not support right-to-left. The best one can do is to try "right alignment", but that does not type punctuation like dot and comma at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tired different clients and [Mailspring](https://getmailspring.com/) does support right-to-left very well. I also tried Thunderbird, Geary, and Evolution but they do not support this although I like some of their features better than Mailspring.